# htaccess rewrite rule two html files only to two php files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

On a website I'm building I needed index.html redirected to index.php

I achieved this with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html?$ / [NC,R,L]
```

in .htaccess and it works perfectly. I now need to add one more file redirect to a file in a sub-directory: membership/become-a-member.html - I've tried adding this with a new rewrite rule and adding it to the existing rule but cannot get it to redirect to membership/become-a-member.php - Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks

`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a new rule for adding `.php` to 2 paths:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.html?$ / [NC,R,L]

RewriteRule ^(become-a-member|another)\.html?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```